# How can you get the SSH return code using Paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

```
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
```

Is there any way to get the command return code?

It's hard to parse all stdout/stderr and know whether the command finished successfully or not.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

SSHClient is a simple wrapper class around the more lower-level functionality in Paramiko.  The [API documentation](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/index.html) lists a [`recv_exit_status()`](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.recv_exit_status) method on the `Channel` class.

A very simple demonstration script:

```
import paramiko
import getpass

pw = getpass.getpass()

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
client.connect('127.0.0.1', password=pw)

while True:
    cmd = raw_input("Command to run: ")
    if cmd == "":
        break
    chan = client.get_transport().open_session()
    print "running '%s'" % cmd
    chan.exec_command(cmd)
    print "exit status: %s" % chan.recv_exit_status()

client.close()
```

Example of its execution:

```
$ python sshtest.py
Password: 
Command to run: true
running 'true'
exit status: 0
Command to run: false
running 'false'
exit status: 1
Command to run: 
$
```

Comment: This is a bad solution. See @apdastous' answer below, it's much better.

Comment: While you are correct about `recv_exit_status`, you cannot use it this way, as the code may deadlock. You have to consume the command output, while waiting for the command to finish. See [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).

Answer (score 347):

A much easier example that doesn't involve invoking the "lower level" channel class directly (i.e. - **NOT** using the `client.get_transport().open_session()` command):

```
import paramiko

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect('blahblah.com')

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("uptime")
print stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()    # status is 0

stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command("oauwhduawhd")
print stdout.channel.recv_exit_status()    # status is 127
```

Comment: What's *nice* about this example is capturing not just EXIT (like the question asks), but demonstrating you can still get STDOUT and STDERR.  

Years ago I was misled by Paramiko's anemic example codebase (no disrespect), and to get EXIT I resorted to low-level transport() calls. transport() seemed to force you to "pick one" (which may not be true, but lack of examples and tutorial docs led me to believe that)...

Comment: While you are correct about `recv_exit_status`, you cannot use it this way, as the code may deadlock. You have to consume the command output, while waiting for the command to finish. See [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848).

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for JanC, I added some modification for the example and tested in Python3, it really useful for me.

```
import paramiko
import getpass

pw = getpass.getpass()

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
#client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

def start():
    try :
        client.connect('127.0.0.1', port=22, username='ubuntu', password=pw)
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        #client.close()
        print(e)
        return False

while start():
    key = True
    cmd = input("Command to run: ")
    if cmd == "":
        break
    chan = client.get_transport().open_session()
    print("running '%s'" % cmd)
    chan.exec_command(cmd)
    while key:
        if chan.recv_ready():
            print("recv:\n%s" % chan.recv(4096).decode('ascii'))
        if chan.recv_stderr_ready():
            print("error:\n%s" % chan.recv_stderr(4096).decode('ascii'))
        if chan.exit_status_ready():
            print("exit status: %s" % chan.recv_exit_status())
            key = False
            client.close()
client.close()
```

Comment: do we get any error message -if any - in chan.recv_stderr_ready()?. Does chan.recv_stderr(4096).decode('ascii') this return a message text?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, output buffering was the problem. Because of buffering, the outputs from the application doesn't come out non-blocking way. You can find the answer about how to print output without buffering in here: [Disable output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering). For short, just run python with -u option like this:

`> python -u script.py`