# Evaluating a remote (Paramiko) ssh command's output into a success/failure boolean

Tags: python, shell, ssh, paramiko

I have a function that checks if a file exists, it returns `'True'`/`'False'`, right now I'm 'converting' it to bool with `eval()`, however I don't think this is the smartest solution, but I'm not sure how else to do it without unnecessary `ifs`,

```py
>>> foo = 'False'
>>> type(eval(foo))
<class 'bool'>
>>> type(foo)
<class 'str'>
```

For example, I'm running this expression, on ssh connected machine

```py
"test -e {0} && echo True || echo False".format(self.repo)
```

like this, and my result is going to be string.

```py
def execute(command):
    (_, stdOut, _) = ssh.exec_command(command)
    output = stdOut.read()
    return output.decode('utf-8')
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: There's no reason for the shell line to echo anything. `test -e {0}` will have an *exit status* of 0 if the expression is true, nonzero (likely 1) otherwise. Test *that*.

Comment: No, the exit status of `ssh` will be the exit status of the command it runs. Whatever you are using to run `ssh` will provide someway to access the integer exit status. (For example, `subprocess.run(['ssh', some_host, f'test -e "{some_file}"']).returncode == 0` (ignoring the issue of ensuring that `some_file` is properly escaped for inclusion in a shell command).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A filename should always be quoted before including it in a context where it might be parsed as code.

Here, we're using the technique introduced in [How can you get the SSH return code using Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562403/how-can-you-get-the-ssh-return-code-using-paramiko) to retrieve exit status directly from the SSH channel, with no need to parse any string passed over stdout.

```
try:
  from pipes import quote  # Python 2.x
except ImportError:
  from shlex import quote  # Python 3.x

def test_remote_existance(filename):
    # assuming that "ssh" is a paramiko SSHClient object
    command = 'test -e {0} </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1'.format(quote(remote_file))
    chan = ssh.get_transport().open_session()
    chan.exec_command(command)
    return chan.recv_exit_status() == 0
```

Comment: Frankly, I consider it a pretty serious design flaw in ssh that it only passes a single string as the remote command to run -- if it passed a full argv array, `quote()` would be unnecessary in its invocation. Alas, we're several decades too late to fix that error.

Comment: Your code will correctly capture the exit code for this specific command that cannot have any output. But had the command produced an output, you cannot directly use recv_exit_status, as the code may deadlock. You have to consume the command output, while waiting for the command to finish. See [Paramiko ssh die/hang with big output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31625788/850848). – Also for this specific task, it's better to use SFTP, instead of shell commands. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59570800/850848#59608563). As a side effect, this would solve all quoting problems.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ast.literal_eval()`. This is safer than `eval()` because it only evaluates literals, not arbitrary expressions.

Comment: This is great, I think I'll be using this, I'll test it out first.

Comment: Though this answers the question you asked, you should not be using that code in the first place. There's no need to convert the exit status to a string when you can get the exit status directly.

Comment: True, although the exit status will still have to be converted: 0 => true, non-zero => false, which is the opposite of Python's truthiness.

Answer (score 1):

To test a file existence over SSH, use the standard API – SFTP, instead of running shell commands.

With Paramiko you can do that by:

```
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
try:
    sftp.stat(path)
    print("File exists")
except IOError:
    print("File does not exist or cannot be accessed")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice in python to return the operation that determines the boolean in python rather than doing something like):

```
if something:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

An example of this using your file checker (this doesn't need to be wrapped in a function but for example's sake:

```
import os

def check_file(infile):
    return os.path.isfile(infile)

print(type(check_file('fun.py'))) # is true # <class 'bool'>
print(type(check_file('nonexistent.txt'))) # is false # <class 'bool'>
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, however in my case I need to run this on another machine, which I'm connected with ssh, so I would need to run `check_file()`, and it will return string again.