# Paramiko does not return segmentation fault error

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

I am trying to make a simple fuzzer for segmentation faults.

```
from pwn import *
import paramiko
import base64

#Setting Vars
#C Program
nameOfFileToExploit = "vuln"

hostname = '10.0.2.15'
port = 22
username = 'kali' 
password = 'kali'
command = 'ls'


context.update(arch='i386', os='linux')

# Connect to the server with SSH
client = paramiko.client.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client.connect(hostname, username=username, password=password)


# Find the point at which the program crashes
for i in range(1, 500):
    _stdin, _stdout,_stderr = client.exec_command('python -c "print( \'A\'*' + str(i) + ')" | /home/kali/Desktop/BufferOverflow/PracOne/vuln')
    stdout = _stdout.readlines()
    print(stdout)
    stderr = _stderr.readlines()
    print(stderr)
    
    if 'Segmentation' in str(stdout):
        # For some reason when sent through pwntools the buffer to crash was 1 length longer than
        # it should have been?
        print('Crash at %d characters' % (i - 1))
        print('Crash at value will be %s' % hex(i - 1))
        break
```

A segmentation fault **should** occur at 31+ characters.

`Please enter your name: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA zsh: segmentation fault  ./vuln`

But despite this being correctly reported by the terminal manually, it **does not appear** in the stderr for paramiko, meaning the if statement is never correct:

Example Output:

```
['Please enter your name: Hi A\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
['Please enter your name: Hi AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA\n']
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
```

Paramiko should return the stderr mentioning the segementation fault. Why is it not?

Comment: This is not C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But despite this being correctly reported by the terminal manually, it does not appear in the stderr for paramiko

This looks to be a `zsh` behavior, and is reproducible without paramiko being involved.  Here's my test setup.  I have a C program that segfaults:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {
  char* c;
  sprintf(c, "hi world");
}
```

When I run this from the terminal I get the following (I'm on OSX so for me it's a "bus error" but the behavior is the same):

```
% ./t                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
zsh: bus error  ./t
```

Here is my invocation in python:

```
import subprocess

res = subprocess.run(["zsh", "-c", "./t"], capture_output=True)
print(res)
print(res.returncode)
```

```
% python3 ./t.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
CompletedProcess(args=['zsh', '-c', './t'], returncode=-10, stdout=b'', stderr=b'')
-10
```

> Paramiko should return the stderr mentioning the segementation fault. Why is it not?

Because running this way, `zsh` doesn't provide the message for paramiko to return.  I don't have an answer to why zsh behaves like this (maybe because the output is not a terminal?).

However, I do have a suggestion that will work for you.  Take `zsh` out of the equation and use `subprocess` in the python command you send through paramiko, and you can benefit from [the behavior of `subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CompletedProcess.returncode):

> A negative value -N indicates that the child was terminated by signal N (POSIX only).

Instead of checking `stdout` your internal python program can check the return code of the process to see if it is equal to `-1 * signal.SIGSEGV`[2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.SIGSEGV)

```
import subprocess, signal

n = 1
while True:
    res = subprocess.run(["./t"], input=bytes('A' * n, "utf-8"), capture_output=True)
    print(res)
    if res.returncode * -1 in [ signal.SIGBUS, signal.SIGSEGV ]:
        break
    n += 1

print(f"{n} As was too many")
```

This gives me

```
% python3 ./t.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          11736ms
CompletedProcess(args=['./t'], returncode=-10, stdout=b'', stderr=b'')
1 As was too many
```

The big difference here is that I'm checking return code, not stderr.  I'm not relying on the shell behavior, though the shell would have the same exit code.  Therefore you could do the same thing at the paramiko level with [How can you get the SSH return code using Paramiko?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562403/how-can-you-get-the-ssh-return-code-using-paramiko)